# I have used a code from and tutorial in that result is coming in the for of toast message i want it in the for of text view

Tags: android

**this this code onclick data is taken from another java file display's as toast message i want it in the for of text

can someone please the text code from the below java code**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm

this is the link from where i used the code

btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

```
    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private TextView textView;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: "
                       + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You want it in what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, initialize you text view like below

```
private TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.you_text_view_id);
```

and on click listener

```
btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    // show location button click event
btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

           // set the text here
           textView.setText("Your Location is - \nLat: "
                   + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Toast` with this code.

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 TextView YourTextView = new TextView(this);

 YourTextView.setText("Your Location is - \nLat: "
                   + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);
 linearLayout.addView(YourTextView);
```

Comment: Ur welcome ! Kindly Accept the answer if it helped you :)